# PHP Overwriting at a specific location in a file

Tags: php

I am trying to write a text at a specific position in a file that already has some content. After writing I find the file truncated to the size of the text plus fseek position and the first characters with value 0. Is this the normal behaviour or am I missing something? I want to mention  that I'm trying to avoid loading  the file into memory and writing it back.

```
$file = fopen("text.txt","w");
fseek($file,3);
fwrite($file,"Hello");
fclose($file);
```

Comment: is your question whether this is normal behaviour, or how to overwrite data in a text file in PHP? because you're asking the former at the moment.

Comment: If I remembered correctly, I have done this in C++ without having any problem. I cannot use "a" since fseek is then ignored, and append mode means append, not overwrite. The question is why this is not working? why is behaving like this? I have read the manual, thank you for suggesting, but what is the purpose of fseek then? just for reading?

Comment: @write2july Read my answer to this question. I quoted the passages from the manual which explain that behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to open the file in `c` mode, else it's truncated on `fopen`:

```
$file = fopen("text.txt","c");
```

See http://php.net/manual/de/function.fopen.php for a documentation of all file open modes and what exactly they do. Also see the http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php manual

Comment: If I remembered correctly, I have done this in C++ without having any problem. I cannot use "a" since fseek is then ignored, and append mode means append, not overwrite. The question is why this is not working? why is behaving like this? I have read the manual, thank you for suggesting, but what is the purpose of fseek then? just for reading?

Comment: I assume c mode is what you're searching for (edited that in). fseek is to my knowledge regularly used for writing, I think your problem was mainly that fopen (i.e. before fseek was even called) truncated the file, and fseek added padding characters before the SEEK_SET position.

Comment: Thank you, it worked with "c". While it is not explicitly specified in the manual fseek works with the file opened in "c" mode.

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch Thanks, It either doesnt exist in the german PHP fseek manual or I must have overread it. Edited that in.

Comment: note that after all your edits, the link for "fileappend" is useless since the answer is not for fopen(..., "a") anymore. (The other two links don't really add much either if no additional code is given that demonstrates how to succesfully overwrite data in a file opened in this manner)

Comment: The German manual was always behind the English manual. Use the English.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans You're right, thanks for the suggestion. Removed that link.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is normal behaviour :

[`fopen($file, "w")`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

> place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and **truncate the file to zero** length.

[`fseek()`](http://www.php.net/fseek):

> In general, it is allowed to seek past the end-of-file; if data is then written, reads in **any unwritten region between the end-of-file and the sought position will yield bytes with value 0**. [..] 
>   If you have opened the file in append (a or a+) mode, any data you write to the file will always be appended, regardless of the file position, and the result of calling fseek() will be undefined.

You probably want to open the file in a non truncating write mode (e.g. "c" but **not "a"**).